# how to navigate from feature file to step definition file in VS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, feature-file, wdio-v6

how can I  navigate from feature file (cucumber framework) to step definition file in WDIO in Visual studio Code.

I have installed all the plugins(Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support v2.15.1,cucumber-gotostep v0.0.4)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Ctrl + Click on the step in the feature file that you would like to navigate to.  Or right click on step and choose "Go To Definition"